# API Яндекс диск

Tags: java, android

Пытаюсь разобраться с api. Выбор пал на api Яндекс диска, но у них нет примеров, половина ссылок на документацию на сайте битые, а т.к. я никогда не работал с api - самому додуматься не получается.

В общем, хотел в приложении через webdav получить доступ к ЯД и получить оттуда ссылки на изображения, но я просто не понимаю, как это делать.

Вполне вероятно, что я слепой, и есть куча примеров с такой тривиальной задачей - буду рад, если дадите на них ссылки.

Comment: Для Яндекс API есть [API клиента на Java](https://github.com/yandex-disk/yandex-disk-sdk-java) в открытом доступе.

Comment: webdav - устаревшая тема. Используй retrofit 2 для осуществления запросов. Писал андроид приложение - все получилось

Comment: Так у них только webdav есть, про retrofit ничего нет. Или взять sdk для webdav и использовать retrofit?

Comment: REST API у них есть, поэтому можно использовать retrofit 2 .

Comment: Ребят, как-то можно получить помощь на этом сайте? 
Я пытаюсь отыскать примеры на Java с api диска, но их нет.
Делал по этому примеру приложение: https://habrahabr.ru/post/314028/ оно работает, но когда я переделал код для работы с яндекс апи, он даже не подключается. Думаю, что дело в токене авторизации, как его правильно указывать?

Comment: там же все элементарно. делай как я тебе говорил с помощью retrofit2 . но для начала изучи протоколы рест и вебдав. Пока ты это не поймешь я не вижу смысла идти дальше.

Comment: Понял, спасибо, реально очень помогло) там же всё ЭЛЕМЕНТАРНО я чего-то сам сидел, думал, ничего не понимал, а тут ты написал, что это ЭЛЕМЕНТАРНО и сразу всё понял, все методы сами написались, запросы, отлично сработано!

Comment: не нужно лезть в дебри пока не знаешь азы! я уже выше написал что учить

Comment: Нужно торопиться. До 6 мая осталось мало времени, школа яндекса ждать не будет 